# Remove elements from a dictionary based on a criteria, in F#

Tags: f#

If I have a mutable dictionary, how can I remove elements based on a criteria?

I thought I can do either:

```
myDict.Keys |> Seq.iter (fun x -> if dict.[x].criteria then dict.Delete(x) |> ignore)
```

or, making a list of keys, use Seq.filter to make a list of keys to remove and then remove all the elements, etc.

but, since I don't know yet all the std library's functions, I was wondering if there is a mechanism to do this?

Comment: The return value of `dict` in F# is read-only, and cannot be mutated: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/extratopleveloperators.dict%5B%27key%2C%27value%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D

Comment: sorry, poor wording, I meant 'dict' as 'myDictionary'; it's a .net dictionary and I will edit the name to clear the confusion

Answer (score 1):

When you say you have a mutable dictionary I'm assuming you mean an System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary and not an F# immutable Dict.  When I use this type of Dictionary in C# I usually end up with code similar to the following F# code (I've run this in a .fsx file in VS2019).

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let dict = new Dictionary<int,int>()
[1..4] |> Seq.iter(fun n -> dict.Add(n,n*n))
dict |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
let removeKeys = dict |> Seq.filter( fun ele -> ele.Value=9) |> Seq.map(fun ele -> ele.Key)
removeKeys
removeKeys |> Seq.iter(fun k -> dict.Remove(k) |> ignore<bool>)
dict |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

So the first thing is to build a list of keys that need to be removed as removing keys while iterating over the dictionary isn't allowed and then iterate over the keys to remove the items from the dictionary.

```
dict |> Seq.iter( fun ele -> if ele.Value=9 then dict.Remove(ele.Key) |> ignore<bool> else ())
```

Trying something like the above causes an InvalidOperationException when dict.Remove gets called (if you try this make sure to repopulate dict, it only fails when the .Remove method is actually called).

As a follow up question I'd suggest you show us why you think you need a mutable dictionary. In a lot of cases there is an approach that allows the F# immutable data structures to be used and if one really is needed there are techniques to encapsulate the mutable data.

Comment: I need a mutable dictionary because it's holding data from a financial stream in a trading system; speed matters *a lot*. So this is similar to the second option I was writing about. I was curious if there was any other way in F#

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered using built-in F# immutable `Map` type? In many cases, mutable dictionaries are a better choice (they are faster), but map lets you do exactly what you're asking for nicely using the `Map.filter` function:

```
Map.ofSeq [ 1, "one"; 2, "two"; 3, "three" ]
|> Map.filter (fun k v -> k % 2 = 1)
```

Comment: yes, that would work, but I need the generic dictionary since speed matters a lot in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In F#, there is a mechanism for the iteration of dictionaries. The active recognizer [`KeyValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.keyvalue%5B%27key,%27value%5D-active-pattern-%5Bfsharp%5D) is used to deconstruct values of the type [`KeyValuePair<'Key,'Value>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2). In a generic dictionary this is the return type of its enumerator's [`Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.current) property.

In .net, there is a mechanism to mutate a dictionary by specifying an individual key to remove an element from the dictionary, the [`Remove(TKey)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove) method.

One of these is functional, the other imperative. One approach creates a new immutable dictionary, the other removes elements from an existing mutable dictionary. Whatever best fits your use case.

```
module Dict =
    open System.Collections.Generic

    // Create a new immutable IDictionary<_,_>, consisting of those 
    // elements for which the predicate function returns true
    let filter predicate source = 
        source |> Seq.choose (function
        | KeyValue(k, v) when predicate k v -> Some(k, v)
        | _ -> None ) |> dict

    // Mutate an existing Dictionary<'a,'b> by removing the keys of those
    // elements for which the predicate function returns true
    let removeWhen predicate (source : Dictionary<_,_>) =
        source |> Seq.choose (function
        | KeyValue(k, v) when predicate k v -> Some k
        | _ -> None )
        |> Seq.toArray
        |> Array.iter (source.Remove >> ignore)

// module Dict = begin
//   val filter :
//     predicate:('a -> 'b -> bool) ->
//       source:seq<KeyValuePair<'a,'b>> -> IDictionary<'a,'b> when 'a : equality
//   val removeWhen :
//     predicate:('a -> 'b -> bool) -> source:Dictionary<'a,'b> -> unit
// end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer; it's similar to the second option I proposed in the question. My question was to see if there is something specific to F# to shortcut that process; from the different answers, it looks like it's not the case.